# Need to add some sort of array and add passing parameters & idea for another class

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class atm{

private static Scanner in;
private static float balance = 0; // initial balance to 0 for everyone
private static int anotherTransaction;

public static void main(String args[]){
    in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // call our transaction method here
    transaction();
}

public static void transaction(){
    // here is where most of the work is

    int choice;

    System.out.println("Please select an option");
    System.out.println("1. Withdraw");
    System.out.println("2. Deposit");
    System.out.println("3. Balance");

    choice = in.nextInt();

    switch(choice){
        case 1:
            float amount;
            System.out.println("Please enter amount to withdraw: ");
            amount = in.nextFloat();
            if(amount > balance || amount == 0){
                System.out.println("You have insufficient funds\n\n");
                anotherTransaction(); // ask if they want another transaction
            } else {
                // they have some cash
                // update balance
                balance = balance - amount;
                System.out.println("You have withdrawn "+amount+" and your new balance is "+balance+"\n");
                anotherTransaction();
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            // option number 2 is depositing
            float deposit;
            System.out.println("Please enter amount you would wish to deposit: ");
            deposit = in.nextFloat();
            // update balance
            balance = deposit + balance;
            System.out.println("You have deposited "+deposit+" new balance is "+balance+"\n");
            anotherTransaction();
            break;

        case 3:
            // this option is to check balance
            System.out.println("Your balance is "+balance+"\n");
            anotherTransaction();
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid option:\n\n");
            anotherTransaction();
            break;
    }

}

public static void anotherTransaction(){
    System.out.println("Do you want another transaction?\n\nPress 1 for another transaction\n2 To exit");
    anotherTransaction = in.nextInt();
    if(anotherTransaction == 1){
        transaction(); // call transaction method
    } else if(anotherTransaction == 2){
        System.out.println("Thanks for choosing us. Good Bye!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid choice\n\n");
        anotherTransaction();
    }
}
```

}

basically i got told off because i didn't have passing parameters in my code, i also need a way of adding an array to this, please help

i also need as suggestion on adding another class but have no ideas

This is a atm system which populates and prints if that helps

Answer (score -1):

you can declare an arrayList (which is what i would use, as utility is a lot simplier) like this; as for rather you should make a class for users, depends heavily on how much detail you want for each user.

```
    package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class main {
    ArrayList<Object> userList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // I'm not sure what your asking. but i think your asking how to declare a arrayList/array

    }


}
```